Wordpress - Contact Form 7 - Get uploaded file issue
I'm aiming to submit my Contact Form 7 data in Wordpress to an API (all fields are fine, but adding the file attachment breaks my submit - error 500), which includes an attachment. I can make it work with a dummy file like so:
$attachedfile = get_template_directory() . '/test.pdf';

$file_contents = file_get_contents($attachedfile);
    $base64_file = base64_encode($file_contents);
    $file_name = basename($attachedfile);
    $mime_type = mime_content_type($attachedfile);

        $documents = [
            [
                'FileName' => $file_name,
                'MimeType' => $mime_type,
                'Base64' => $base64_file,
            ],
        ];

This sends the file to the server, and it receives it fine. But I need to do it dynamically through the form.
So I constructed this function:
function my_custom_form_submission($contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($submission) {
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        
        
        $email = isset($data['your-email']) ? sanitize_email($data['your-email']) : '';
        $phone = 'Nincs megadva';
        $lastname = isset($data['your-name']) ? sanitize_text_field($data['your-name']) : '';
        $firstname = isset($data['text-532']) ? sanitize_text_field($data['text-532']) : '';
        $companyname = isset($data['text-479']) ? sanitize_textarea_field($data['text-479']) : '';
        $created = current_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); 


        $branch = isset($data['menu-586']) ? sanitize_textarea_field($data['menu-586']) : '';
        if ($branch == 'Divat / Design') {
            $flow = 'DivatDesign';
        } else {
            $flow = 'Startup';
        }

        $uploaded_files = $submission->uploaded_files();
        
        
        // if (!empty($uploaded_files)) {
            
        //     $uploaded_file = $uploaded_files['file-524'];

        //     // Read file contents
        //     $file_content = file_get_contents($uploaded_file);

        //     if ($file_content !== false) {
        //         // Encode file content in base64
        //         $base64_file = base64_encode($file_content);

        //         // Prepare data array for API
        //         $documents = array(
        //             'FileName' => $uploaded_file['name'],
        //             'MimeType' => $uploaded_file['type'],
        //             'Base64' => 'data:' . $uploaded_file['type'] . ';base64,' . $base64_file
        //         );
        //     }
        // }
       

        //error_log('Uploaded File Path: ' . $attachedfile);

         if (wf_checkEmail($email) == false) {
            $userId = saveToWf($email, $lastname, $firstname);

            //Log the userId for debugging
             error_log('User ID: ' . $userId);
            
            if ($userId) {
                registerToWf($email, $lastname, $firstname, $flow, $userId, $companyname, $phone, $attachedfile, $branch, $documents);
            }
        } 
    }
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_custom_form_submission');

Issue is, if I submit my form like this, it works for all fields, however if I comment out the fields related to $uploaded_files, it breaks the submit with an 500 error. I have found no way to see (output / dump) what $uploaded_files exactly returns, but I'm guessing it's something different than my dummy file.
There is only 1 file uploaded, so I don't need a foreach. Anyone done something similar, or can point me in the right direction? I was not able to find anything on this.

Also it's worth noting that I only have FTP access to their server, and wp_debug seems to be disabled somehow. No log is visible despite having define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); in wp_config.


Try this
function my_custom_form_submission( $contact_form ) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) {
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        
        $email = isset( $data['your-email'] ) ? sanitize_email( $data['your-email'] ) : '';
        $phone = 'Nincs megadva';
        $lastname = isset( $data['your-name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $data['your-name'] ) : '';
        $firstname = isset( $data['text-532'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $data['text-532'] ) : '';
        $companyname = isset( $data['text-479'] ) ? sanitize_textarea_field( $data['text-479'] ) : '';
        $created = current_time( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s' ); 

        $branch = isset( $data['menu-586'] ) ? sanitize_textarea_field( $data['menu-586'] ) : '';
        if ( $branch == 'Divat / Design' ) {
            $flow = 'DivatDesign';
        } else {
            $flow = 'Startup';
        }

        $uploaded_files = $submission->uploaded_files();
        $documents = [];

        if ( ! empty( $uploaded_files ) ) {
            $uploaded_file = $uploaded_files['file-524'];

            // Read file contents
            $file_content = file_get_contents( $uploaded_file );

            if ( $file_content !== false ) {
                // Encode file content in base64
                $base64_file = base64_encode( $file_content );

                // Prepare data array for API
                $documents = [
                    [
                        'FileName' => basename( $uploaded_file ),
                        'MimeType' => mime_content_type( $uploaded_file ),
                        'Base64' => $base64_file,
                    ],
                ];
            }
        }

        if ( wf_checkEmail( $email ) == false ) {
            $userId = saveToWf( $email, $lastname, $firstname );

            // Log the userId for debugging
            error_log( 'User ID: ' . $userId );
            
            if ( $userId ) {
                registerToWf( $email, $lastname, $firstname, $flow, $userId, $companyname, $phone, $attachedfile, $branch, $documents );
            }
        } 
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_custom_form_submission' );

Make sure the file-524 matches the name of the file upload field in your Contact Form 7 setup. Also, ensure the file permissions allow reading the uploaded file on the server.
To debug the issue, you can temporarily add error logging to check the contents of $uploaded_files:
error_log( print_r( $uploaded_files, true ) );

This will help you see what $uploaded_files actually contains and adjust your code accordingly.
